# Can we do Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) via https

Tags: rest, web, https, cors

I am new to Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) where I need to invoke a REST endpoint via https from Javascript.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can invoke a REST endpoint via https from Javascript, all you need to do is just enable CORS.

Comment: Can you please share some links which shows how this can be done?